# Can we read data from TXT file and save it to SQL database using C and C++?

Tags: c++, sql, c

is it possible to read data from TXT file and convert it to SQL database and then try some SQL queries all using C and C++?

Example of the TXT file:

```
CityId Name Inhabitants AreaId Elevation
101 London 8908081 103 334
22 Barcelona1620343 24 309
26 Berlin 3429870 27 34
```

So, I would like to make SQL table and store the informations into the table and then I want to try some queries to get some information about cities. (All using C code (if possible) or using C++ code)

Comment: you can make your database using Management studio , then this link explains how you can send a query to your data base https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/341111/How-to-connect-SQL-Server-to-Cplus-Program

Answer (score 0):

I think the reading and making the database part is possible. but however i dont think it would be all that easy to run queries with c or c++.
queries has to be done through a dbms like Mariadb